# Swift - Using Facebook Authentication of Firebase occur (INVALID_CREDENTIALS) error

Tags: swift, firebase, facebook-authentication, firebase-authentication

Facebook login is no problem but firebase cannot get Facebook account detail.

1. I have checked what INVALID_CREDENTIALS means in firebase website
2. I checked facebook app ID and secret.
3. I deleted all the  IP Whitelist

Once I build, it shows:

> Loged in
>
> Login failed. Error Domain=FirebaseAuthentication Code=-11 "(Error Code: INVALID_CREDENTIALS) Invalid authentication credentials provided." UserInfo={details={"providerErrorInfo":{}}, NSLocalizedDescription=(Error Code: INVALID_CREDENTIALS) Invalid authentication credentials provided.}

```
@IBAction func loginWithFB(sender: AnyObject) {
    let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()
    //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("CurrentlyLoggedIn", sender: sender)
    facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], fromViewController: self, handler: {(facebookResult, facebookError) -> Void in
        if facebookError != nil {
            print("Facebook login failed. Error \(facebookError)")
        } else if facebookResult.isCancelled {
            print("Facebook login was cancelled.")
        }else{
            print("Loged in")
            let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
            
            DataService.dataService.BASE_REF.authWithOAuthProvider("facebook", token: accessToken, withCompletionBlock: {error, authData in
                if error != nil{
                    print("Login failed. \(error)")
                }else{
                    print("Logged in! \(authData)")
                }})
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this lines of codes in your project. I think your completion handler trigger this case. This below works on my project.

```
  let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

  facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self) { (facebookResult: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, facebookError: NSError!) in

        if facebookError == nil {
            if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil {
                print("FOUND NIL!")
            }
            else if(facebookResult.isCancelled) {
                print("Cancelled")
            }
            else {
                let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
                print(accessToken)

                DataService.ds.REF_BASE.authWithOAuthProvider("facebook", token: accessToken, withCompletionBlock: {
                    error, authData in

                    if error != nil {
                        print("yes \(error)")
                    }
                    else {

                        print("Logged in! \(authData)")

                    }
                })

            }
        }

   }
```